# How to apply styles to parent CSS class from child CSS class

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, styles

let's consider an example

```
 .parent-class{
    width: 20px;
  }
 .child-class{
    width: 5px;
  }
```

I just want to apply the `height: 10px` style to `.parent-class` by using `.child-class` name.
let's consider HTML code just like below

```
<div class="parent-class">
  parent
   <div class="some-other-class">
       internal
       <div class="child-class">
       child
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

***I don't want to use the `.parent-class` name while applying `height: 10px` style to it***

I appreciate your help, Thanks!

Comment: Is child-class element a direct child of the parent-class element? Showing the typical HTML structure would help us.

Comment: CSS stands for *Cascading* style sheet, you can't access it backwards.

Answer (score 0):

There is this :has() selector for that.

```css
.parent-class:has(.child-class){height: 10px;}
```

Cheers